# How to stick text over an image in html (zoom in/out, change resolution)?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to stick a text over an image. When I zoom in/zoom out, the text heads in another direction than the image, but I want them to move along together.
I am also using media queries for some resolutions, but I can not use media-queries for every given resolution. So how can I solve this problem?

I tried using media-queries and using absolute/relative positions for the containers.

```
<div class="container-fluid test img-responsive">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-center col-md-6 waben">
                            <img class="wabeeins pull-left img-responsive" src="https://i.ibb.co/f23d7qk/Artboard-1.png"
                                height="298.39" width="344.56" id="wabeone" alt=wabe1>
                            <div class="firsttext">
                                <h1>Test <br> test <br> test!</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
@media (min-width: 1700px)
{
  .wabeeins{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-left: -8%;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  .firsttext {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 12%;
    right: 32%;
    font-family: $font;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
  }
}
```

I have tried using it without bootstrap and it pretty much worked, but I still could not figure it out, how to get things done with bootstrap.

I expect to move text and image on the same time, in the same direction. I also want to have a responsive-layout for every given resolution, as I can not handle every resolution with @media... (for example when someone is shrinking the browser size)

Comment: You are mixing BS3 and BS4 styles fyi

Comment: Solving that, did not change my problem. Furthermore is this tutorial https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-using-css.php working without bootstrap. When using the above mentioned code, it is not working as supposed. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write position relative for parent div and write position absolute for child div. if you need center position add transform property. you can use this code for all resolution.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid test img-responsive">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-center col-md-6 waben">
                            <img class="wabeeins pull-left img-responsive" src="https://i.ibb.co/f23d7qk/Artboard-1.png"
                                height="298.39" width="344.56" id="wabeone" alt=wabe1>
                            <div class="firsttext">
                                <h1>Test <br> test <br> test!</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.waben{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.firsttext{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```